# Mongoose: Why to convert a received data toObject

Tags: express, mongoose, lodash

I was learning mongoose, and I am trying to figure out.
Why toObject() was needed to convert the data received into Object, when it was already in object form it seems

Here is the code:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var user = this;
  var userObject = user.toObject();

  return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email']);
};
```

I cannot understand why toObject() was used to extract the meaningful properties from the object.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you console.log(user) and find out what does it contain? In this case `this` probably holds a reference to something you did not expect :). Play with the console.log and see what it shows you.

Comment: okay! Thanks Akrion

Comment: You re welcome. If you found this helpful please mark that as the answer so others can find the answer to your question easier.

Answer (score 0):

`toObject` is a mongoose document method `Document.prototype.toObject()` which:

> Converts this document into a plain javascript object, ready for storage in MongoDB.

[You can more about it here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

The reason it is called there is because a plain JS object is required in order to do the lodash `_.pick` which would create a new object with only `_id` and `email` properties.